# Codeigniter: Controller function name shows in url, how change to view file name?

Tags: codeigniter, url, controller, routes

wondering if anyone can guide me to what ive done wrong (or need to do) and think the problem is in my routes file. When the user is displayed the login form and for example they get their username wrong after submit the url displays as this: `http://localhost:8888/codeigniter/login/login_validation`. When the are successful and log into the admin area (which pulls news articles from the db) this url is still shown. I am wondering if there is a way to make it to `http://localhost:8888/codeigniter/news.` I have looked in my routes folder and i tried to use 'wildcards' and was unsuccessful. Here is my code for reference, any other info or files needed let me know! Thanks.

CONTROLLER:

```
  class Login extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();

    }

        public function index() {
            $this->load->view('login');
    }


    //Validate login area
    public function login_validation() {
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'trim|required|xss_clean|callback_username_check');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required|xss_clean|callback_password_check');

          if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
             //Field validation failed.  User redirected to login page
             $this->index();

             }else{
                 $this->load->model('user_model');
                 $query = $this->user_model->login_details();

                 // if the user's credentials validated...
                if($query) {
                    $data = array(
                        'username' => $this->input->post('username'),
                        'is_logged_in' => true
                    );

                    $this->session->set_userdata($data);
                    redirect('news');

                }else{
                 $data['error'] ="Invalid Username or Password";
                 $this->load->view('login',$data);  
                }

            }
    }

            function logout() {
       $this->session->sess_destroy();
       $this->index();
}
```

}

login_details function from user_model.php

```
           function login_details() {
        $this->db->where('username', $this->input->post('username'));
        $this->db->where('password', md5($this->input->post('password')));
        $query = $this->db->get('login');

        if($query->num_rows == 1){
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're logging into any kind of system, you're going to need to store a session using CodeIgniter's [Session](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html) class. Provided `controllers/news.php` exists, you can set the session and immediately just perform a redirect with `redirect('news');`. No need to `$this->load->view()` because this logic will be in `news.php`'s index anyway and you'd be duplicating code.

I'm not sure what `$this->user_model->login_details()` is returning, but I'm assuming `false` or `null` because you say CodeIgniter is sending you back to the `login` view. Head into the `login_details()` function and make sure things are working properly (you might want to post it too). Also, post your `routes.php` file for us if you made changes just in case.

On a side note: Space is a valid password character, don't `trim` it or folks with leading or trailing space's in their passwords won't be able to get in ;)

Comment: After your great advice, this has changed the url to `/codeigniter/news`. Now a codeigniter error has displayed saying 'the page you requested cannot be found'. The news.php is in the same file as all the other files as well. I will edit my code above to show you the corrected code after your advice to see how i changed this.Thanks for the heads up on the trim password error, i actually took that method from a tutorial so i will make sure to look at the userguide carefully next time! i will also post my login_details function so you can see what this pulls into the controller.

Comment: I also have form, url, sessions and database currently on autoload and my routes is. simply $route['news'] = "news"; In the config file the base url is set up with localhost and the file name (works for other files).

Comment: FIXED: I had duplicated a function in two controllers. Thanks again for your advice.